# Differences between for-auto loops

Tags: c++

What is the difference between these two loops for a `std::string s`:

```
for (char c : s) { /* do something */ }
```

```
for (char& c : s} { /* do something */}
```

Does the first make the copy of every element, whereas the second is a reference? Would something like:

```
for (const char& c : s) {/* do something */
```

ever be used if the elements aren't being altered?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes.

Comment: Exactly the same as for passing `char c` to a function with a `char/char&/const char&` parameter.

Comment: Yes, the first will copy every char of the string, the second is just a reference into memory where string s is already placed char by char.
I'm not certain about the const char tho.. i would say it is just to loop throught it, not for altering elements.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you do

```cpp
for ( <your code> : s) 
{
 ...
}
```

The `<your code>` part is run for each element of `s` (it can be an array or some other STL collection that can be iterated upon).

So in the first case,

```cpp
for (char c : s) { /* do something */ }
```

a local copy `c` is created for each element in `s`. You are allowed to change `c`, but it will not affect `s`.

Moving on to the second case,

```cpp
for (char &c : s) { /* do something */ }
```

A reference variable `c` is created for each element in `s`. Thus, changing `c` will also change the elements `s`, since we are not creating a local copy of the characters within `s`, unlike in the previous case. However, this (modifying a collection while iterating it) is deemed a bad practice. It might be easy enough to handle in your simple program, but in large projects with multiple threads running, ensuring that the collection is not modified is helpful to write maintainable code and avoid pitfalls.

Now finally,

```cpp
for (const char& c : s) { /* do something */ }
```

You have created a `const` reference of characters in the collection `s`. This makes it similar to case 1, but now changing the value will cause a compile-time error, since `c` is declared as `const`.

This does seem to be pointless in this specific case, but if you wish to iterate for your custom class type, for which you do not wish to allocate memory while creating a copy (as was done in the first case), then it makes perfect sense to create `const` references of that custom type as shown here.

Comment: So does this mean that a `for(int k = 0 ; k < s.size() ; k++) {/* do something with s[k] */}` is more efficient than the `for (char c : s)` version? Or is it just about the same since you're still allocating an integer vs. a character. Someone above mentioned it's like a function call, but is it that way in the assembly?

Comment: @user8393252 Usually, the `for (<> : <collection>)` iteration is made to be the most efficient way of iteration for all STL data structures.  Since std::string is implemented as an array of `char`, you would not be making much difference in choosing either of them.

Comment: @user8393252 I'm not sure I understood your last question correctly. Running such code in assembly shows that the [compiler can optimize this code](https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/qsjE7rWEc) so that it is an iterative process rather than a function call. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @user8393252 Glad to help. You may upvote my answer.